# Pulling down data from Firebase resulting in crash

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get some data from Firebase. My Firebase structure is as follows:

```
"groups": {
   group-key (random key generated by firebase): {
      "creationDate": 
      "dropbox": 
      "endDate": 
      "evernote": 
      "googleDocs": 
      "members": {
               "0": user 1
               "1": user 2 
               "2": user 3 etc....
      }
     "projectName": 
     "subject": 
   }
}
```

I'm trying to pull down all the date from the `groups` child with this code:

```
private List<DataService> grouplist;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDBRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("groups");
grouplist = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

grouplist.clear();

        mDBRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


            String creationDate = (String) dataSnapshot.child("creationDate").getValue();
            String dropbox = (String) dataSnapshot.child("dropbox").getValue();
            String endDate = (String) dataSnapshot.child("endDate").getValue();
            String evernote = (String) dataSnapshot.child("evernote").getValue();
            String googleDocs = (String) dataSnapshot.child("googleDocs").getValue();
            String members = (String) dataSnapshot.child("members").getValue();
            String projectName = (String) dataSnapshot.child("projectName").getValue();
            String subject = (String) dataSnapshot.child("subject").getValue();

            DataService dataService = new DataService();
            dataService.setCreationDate(creationDate);
            dataService.setDropbox(dropbox);
            dataService.setEndDate(endDate);
            dataService.setEvernote(evernote);
            dataService.setGoogleDocs(googleDocs);
            dataService.setmembers(members);
            dataService.setProjectName(projectName);
            dataService.setSubject(subject);

            grouplist.add(dataService);

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(grouplist));

        }         
    });
}
```

And my DataSerivice.java

```
public class DataService {
public String subject;
public String projectName;
public String endDate;
public String members;
public String creationDate;
public String dropbox;
public String evernote;
public String googleDocs;

public DataService() {
}

public DataService(String subject, String projectName, String endDate, String members, String creationDate, String dropbox, String evernote, String googleDocs) {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.members = members;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.dropbox = dropbox;
    this.evernote = evernote;
    this.googleDocs = googleDocs;
}

public String getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public String getDropbox() {
    return dropbox;
}

public void setDropbox(String dropbox) {
    this.dropbox = dropbox;
}

public String getEvernote() {
    return evernote;
}

public void setEvernote(String evernote) {
    this.evernote = evernote;
}

public String getGoogleDocs() {
    return googleDocs;
}

public void setGoogleDocs(String googleDocs) {
    this.googleDocs = googleDocs;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getmembers() {
    return members;
}

public void setmembers(String members) {
    this.members = members;
}

}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

My guess is that the problem is with the "members" child and to get the users from there. Am I on the right track/ what is wrong or is there a better way to do this? Appreciate all help.

[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZyM2.png)

Comment: Exception clearly says what is an error. Somewhere in your database, data is saved as `Long` and you are trying to cast it in `String` so either try to find where or use `String.valueOf()` for example: `String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("creationDate").getValue())`

Comment: Please add a screenshot of a single `group-key` object to see the properties more clearly. Please responde with @.

Comment: I added a screenshot above @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are having in your model class the `creationDate` set of type String while in your database the `creationDate` holds a `long`. To solve this, in your model class change the type of your property from `String` to `long`:

```
public long creationDate;
```

And please also change the corresponding setter and getter to:

```
public long getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(long creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}
```

The constructor should also be changed like so:

```
public DataService(String subject, String projectName, String endDate, String members, long creationDate, String dropbox, String evernote, String googleDocs) {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.members = members;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.dropbox = dropbox;
    this.evernote = evernote;
    this.googleDocs = googleDocs;
}
```

In the end, just change the following line of code:

```
String creationDate = (String) dataSnapshot.child("creationDate").getValue();
```

to

```
long creationDate = dataSnapshot.child("creationDate").getValue(Long.class);
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

try using this way

```
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            DataService creationDate = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataService.class);
            grouplist.add(dataService);
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(grouplist));
        }
```

you are facing the error because you are trying to cast you value object to string class. so you use the upper stated code you simply you can call the `toString()` method with each `getValue()` value method as

`String creationDate = dataSnapshot.child("creationDate").getValue().toString();
//convert land value to String value not into the String class object`

One more thing you need to change your `String member` to `List<User> member`and change its setter and getter method of data type List too.

**Remember :** I'm supposing User is a class which have the data of users. if it is a simple String then you can use String instead of User

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
        String creationDate = (String) dataSnapshot.child("creationDate").getValue();
        String dropbox = (String) dataSnapshot.child("dropbox").getValue();
        String endDate = (String) dataSnapshot.child("endDate").getValue();
        String evernote = (String) dataSnapshot.child("evernote").getValue();
        String googleDocs = (String) dataSnapshot.child("googleDocs").getValue();
        String members = (String) dataSnapshot.child("members").getValue();
        String projectName = (String) dataSnapshot.child("projectName").getValue();
        String subject = (String) dataSnapshot.child("subject").getValue();
```

Do it like this

```
        String creationDate = dataSnapshot.child("creationDate").getValue().toString();
        String dropbox = dataSnapshot.child("dropbox").getValue().toString();
        String endDate = dataSnapshot.child("endDate").getValue().toString();
        String evernote = dataSnapshot.child("evernote").getValue().toString();
        String googleDocs = dataSnapshot.child("googleDocs").getValue().toString();
        String members = dataSnapshot.child("members").getValue().toString();
        String projectName = dataSnapshot.child("projectName").getValue().toString();
        String subject = dataSnapshot.child("subject").getValue().toString();
```

toString() is used to convert any value to string. You cannot cast anything to string like you are doing.

Also, this code

```
        DataService dataService = new DataService();
        dataService.setCreationDate(creationDate);
        dataService.setDropbox(dropbox);
        dataService.setEndDate(endDate);
        dataService.setEvernote(evernote);
        dataService.setGoogleDocs(googleDocs);
        dataService.setmembers(members);
        dataService.setProjectName(projectName);
        dataService.setSubject(subject);
        grouplist.add(dataService);
```

can be replaced by this

```
        DataService dataService = new DataService(subject, projectName, endDate, members, creationDate, dropbox, evernote, googleDocs);
        grouplist.add(dataService);
```

Or this,

```
        grouplist.add(new DataService(subject, projectName, endDate, members, creationDate, dropbox, evernote, googleDocs));
```

As you have already created constructor for this class.

Comment: If I add .toString() I receive this error message: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference